# Deploy App Engine version from Python with service account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to deploy an App Engine instance from Python by using service account. The goal is to spin up a lot of instances, do some heavy network task (download and upload files) and shut them down afterwords. 
I'm trying to do it with service account from Python runtime, but getting the following error

```
TypeError: Missing required parameter "servicesId"
```

What could be wrong or is there a better solution for such task? Thanks and the code is below:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

gcp = build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
res = gcp.apps().create(body={"id":"251499913983"})

app_json = {
  "deployment": {
    "files": {
        "my-resource-file1": {
          "sourceUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/downloader_sources/hello-world/main.py"
        }
      }
  },
  "handlers": [
    {
      "script": {
        "scriptPath": "main.app"
      },
      "urlRegex": "/.*"
    }
  ],
  "runtime": "python27",
  "threadsafe": True
}
res2 = gcp.apps().services().versions().create(body=app_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to specify the service you want to deploy to. You could use default:

```
gcp.apps().services().versions().create(serviceID=default, body=app_json)
```

See [doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/appengine/v1/python/latest/appengine_v1.apps.services.versions.html) for more details.